# Draw lines on a NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I am trying to draw lines joinning 15 random points on a NSView, but I don't see the any line.
StretchView.h:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface StretchView : NSView {
    NSBezierPath *myPath;
}

-(NSPoint)randomPoint;

@end
```

StretchView.m:

```
    #import "StretchView.h"

@implementation StretchView

-(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame{

    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        srandom(time(NULL));
        myPath=[[NSBezierPath alloc]init];
        [myPath setLineWidth:1.5]; //width of the lines
        NSPoint aPoint= [self randomPoint];
        [myPath moveToPoint:aPoint];
        for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
            aPoint=[self randomPoint]; //call the function randomPoint defined below 

            [myPath lineToPoint:aPoint]; //join the following point

        }

        [myPath closePath];  

    }
    return self;
}
```

Definition of random point, it provides a point with a random x field from x origin coordinate  to the width size. And with the y field from the y origin coordinate to the height size:

```
-(NSPoint)randomPoint
{
    NSPoint result;
    NSRect r= [self bounds];
    result.x=r.origin.x+random()%(int)r.size.width;
    result.y=r.origin.y+random()%(int)r.size.height;
    return result;
}
```

Function of drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

        NSRect bounds=[self bounds];
        [[NSColor greenColor]set];
        [NSBezierPath fillRect:bounds];
        [[NSColor whiteColor]setStroke];
        [myPath stroke];

    }

    @end
```

Comment: Did you step through `randomPoint` to make sure you're getting sensible values?

Comment: My initial question would be what is `frame` during `-initWithFrame:`, because `bounds` might be invalid or different than it is when `-drawRect:` runs. I know this is probably just a test project, but ... when I do this kind of thing I lazily rebuild `myPath` in `-drawRect:` once, whenever `bounds` changes. (i.e. keep `myPath` and `myPathRect`, compare the latter against `bounds`, rebuild the path iff it changes, then draw it.

Comment: Also consider using the `arc4_random...()` family: it's easier and doesn't have to be seeded.